# реализация setValue();

Tags: java, jtable

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать метод setValue() для редактирования определённой ячейки. Вот код модели таблицы.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
public class CarTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7613144437359017913L;


private int columnCount = 4;
private ArrayList<String[]> dataArrayList;


public CarTableModel(){
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for(int i=0; i<dataArrayList.size(); i++ ){
        dataArrayList.add(new String[getColumnCount()]);        
    }
}


@Override
public int getRowCount() {

    return dataArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {

    return columnCount;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
    switch(columnIndex){
    case 0: return "ID машины.";
    case 1: return "Марка машины.";
    case 2: return "Модель.";
    case 3: return "Номер машины.";     
    }

    return "";
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    String []rows = dataArrayList.get(rowIndex);

    return rows[columnIndex];
}

public void setValue(String newValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){

}

public void addDate(String []row){
    String []rowTable = new String[getColumnCount()];
    rowTable = row;
    dataArrayList.add(rowTable);

}


public void removeRow(int row) {
    dataArrayList.remove(row);

}
}
```

Comment: `dataArrayList.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = newValue`?

Comment: а, стоп. не `setValue`, а `setValueAt(Object newValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` (используйте аннотацию `@Override` чтобы ловить такие ошибки), тогда `dataArrayList.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = String.valueOf( newValue )`. Ну и `getColumnClass` стоит переопределить.

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.